# d3js parse and find the number of data set

Tags: html, d3.js

I'm a newbie in d3js  and i have to create an svg image(dynamic: with respect to width and height) by parsing a CSV file. CSV file contains repeative  two columns . and according that only i have to set my width and height of an CSV image and the same dat should be used to create the images which are mostly different shape as per the data. currently i made a fixed size image and i'm unable to write name in the left hand side.

```
<script>
var dataset =[]; var datasetx =[]; var datasety =[];var datasett =[];
var geneset =[]; var genesetx =[]; var genesety =[];var genesett =[];
var genesetxp =20; var genesetyp =20;
var xscale =60; var yscale =40; var xspace=40;var wspace=40;
var xdatascale =10; var ydatascale =20;
var radius =15; x1=32;
var gene=[];    var input ;var geney=[];
var genelist =[];   
d3.csv("data/test.csv", function(data) { 

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("height",500)
.attr("width",1000)

var labeldata = canvas.selectAll("text")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.transition()
.delay(1)
.duration(1500)
.attr("x",function(d){

var labelx =d.target;
var labelx_len = datasetx.length; 
var labelxmatches=0;


for( var i=0; i<labelx_len; i++)
{
if(datasetx[i]==labelx)
{
    labelxmatches++;
}
}
if(labelxmatches==0)
{
datasetx.push(d.target);
xdatascale=xdatascale+wspace;
return xdatascale;
}


})

.attr("y", function(d){


var labelx =d.target;
var labelx_len = datasety.length; 
var labelxmatches=0;


for( var i=0; i<labelx_len; i++)
{
if(datasety[i]==labelx)
{
    labelxmatches++;
}
}
if(labelxmatches==0)
{
datasety.push(d.target);
return ydatascale;
}

})
.attr("transform", function(d){ 
var labelx =d.target;
var labelx_len = datasett.length; 
var labelxmatches=0;


for( var i=0; i<labelx_len; i++)
{
if(datasett[i]==labelx)
{
    labelxmatches++;
}
}
if(labelxmatches==0)
{
datasett.push(d.target);
x1=x1+wspace; return "rotate(270 "+ x1+",25)";
}   
})

.text(function(d){
var labelx =d.target;
var labelx_len = dataset.length; 
var labelxmatches=0;


for( var i=0; i<labelx_len; i++)
{
if(dataset[i]==labelx)
{
    labelxmatches++;
}
}
if(labelxmatches==0)
{
dataset.push(d.target);
return d.target;
}
})





var visual = canvas.selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("svg:circle")
.transition()
.delay(1)
.duration(1500)
.attr("cx",function(d)
{
var matches =0;
var input =d.source;
var total_len = gene.length; 
for( var i=0; i<total_len; i++)
{
if(gene[i]==input)
{
    matches++;
}
}
if(matches==0)
{
xscale =60;
gene.push(d.source);

}
else
{
xscale=xscale+xspace; 
}
return xscale;
})
.attr("cy",function(d)
{

var matches =0;
var input =d.source;

var total_len = geney.length; 
for( var i=0; i<total_len; i++)
{
if(gene[i]==input)
{
    matches++;
}
}
if(matches==0){yscale =yscale+xspace;   geney.push(d.source);}return yscale;})
.attr("r", radius)
.style("fill", function(d){var fcolor;if(d.ExpressionRatio == ""){fcolor="black";}else if(d.ExpressionRatio < "0"){fcolor="blue";}if(d.ExpressionRatio =="0"){fcolor="green";}if(d.ExpressionRatio >"0"){fcolor="red";}
return fcolor;}); 


$('svg circle').tipsy({ 
gravity: 'w', 
html: true, 
title: function(d) {
var d = this.__data__, gene = d.source , Consequence =d.Consequence, ExpressionRatio= d.ExpressionRatio, CNVRatio =d.CNVRatio;
return '<b>Gene:</b>' + gene + '<br><b>Consequence:</b>'+Consequence+'<br><b>ExpressionRatio:</b>'+ExpressionRatio+'<br><b>CNVRatio:</b>'+CNVRatio+''; 
}
});






xscale=xscale+xspace;







})


</script>
```

Comment: Could you maybe narrow it down to the specific code that you're having a problem with?

Comment: actually i have two problems;
1) how to set the size of svg dynamically depending on the data set
2) When i try to in co-operate  different text both horizontally and vertically with varying  x and y i was only able to see one text